# Where are Queries performed in Yii Framework

Tags: mysql, pdo, frameworks, yii

Im using the Yii Framework (v 1.1.14). Where in the frame are the queries performaned (I want to measure the performance and build in a caching-system.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out line 470 of CDBCommand.php, under yii/framework/db. This is mostly used by querybuilder:

```
private function queryInternal($method,$mode,$params=array()) {
```

also, 316 of CDBCommand.php, this is mostly used by CActiveRecord:

```
public function execute($params=array()) {
```

All the relevant profiling and logging methods are already included for you, you just have to switch them on. The instructions are provided in the link in my comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Samuel!

Regarding the profiling: I´m to sure, how to enable it. The docs just says: "By setting CDbConnection::enableProfiling to be true in the application configuration" - but how (and where) do I set it true (Im new to the yii framework)?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: okay, I just did here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26141105/where-can-i-find-the-mysql-logs-in-yii-framework. Too bad, that I can not upvote your answer (reputation < 15).