# Where can I find the MySQL Logs in Yii Framework

Tags: logging, yii, frameworks, profiling

I found this docs to enable the MySQL logging in the Yii Framework (my goal is it to improve the performance):
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/235/configuring-cweblogroute-for-db-profiling/

Where can I the logs (after running the application)?

Thanks!

Comment: By default in `/protected/runtime/application.log`

Comment: @chris - I cant found that directory. I´m using xampp on windows, so I already checked C:\xampp\apache\logs.

Comment: Wel did you mean the Yii profiling logs? These should be in `htdocs/your-app/protected/runtime` If you meant the mysql server logs, these need to be activated first I guess. See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-logs.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use CWebLogRoute for logging then you can see your logs in your browser, just below content (like in example you provided).

You can also use CFileLogRoute, and Yii will create a application.log file in *protected/runtime*. In addition you can define fileName and filePath so you can log db messages in different log file.

```
'db'=>array(
    'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=name',
    'emulatePrepare' => true,
    'username' => 'username',
    'password' => 'password',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'enableParamLogging'=>true,
),
'log'=>array(
    'class'=>'CLogRouter',
    'routes'=>array(
        array(
            'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
            'levels'=>'error, warning',
        ),
        array(
            'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
            'levels'=>'trace',
            'categories'=>'system.db.CDbCommand',
            'fileName'=>'db.log',
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: Also if you want to see param values in your queries just add param logging in your db config array
'db'=>array(
...
'enableParamLogging'=>true,
...
),